# What is the syntax for importing / requiring NPM modules with Angular in app.js?

Tags: angularjs, npm, ionic-framework, require

I am using Ionic and AngularJS to build a mobile application.

I have an API that I have to use (not sure I can say what due to stupid NDA stuff).

But in the documentation it requires an `npm install`. Currently, I'm learning Ionic, and I'm wondering about what to do with this? How do I import my API with Angular so I can make a call?

Node:

`var api = require('npm-api');` (This, but in Angular.)

`api.doSomething({...});` Etc...

So that's basically how it looks in node. How can I do this with Angular? I love Angular's MV*, especially for this Ionic mobile app, so I'm wondering what the best, most efficient way to do this is.

Comment: npm install doesn't mean it can only be used with require('modulename').. You could always have a grunt/gulp task that copies a minified file from a dist folder into your public (or static asset) folder and include it like any other script.

Comment: @KevinB Is there another way? If I don't have a minified file, for example?

Comment: First question to that would be does the module even support being ran in the browser? if so, it'd likely need to be browserified first if it doesn't come with a pre-built minified version.

Comment: Could you maybe give a resource that goes over that particular workflow? I 've been looking at browserify with no luck on actually getting it working.

Comment: Unfortunately no, other than what you'd get with a simple google search. I haven't been through very many browserify tutorials.

Comment: Try cg-angular: https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular I already use in a lot of projects